# FB.API access token for reading page feed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to read a feed from a public page. The idea is to display the feed on a private company intranet, without needing users to login to facebook.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_UK/all.js', function(){
    FB.init({
      appId: 'APP_ID_I_INSERTED_IT ',
    });     



    FB.api(
    "/PUBLIC_PAGE_NAME_I_PUT_HERE/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        console.log('FB:' + response);
      }
      else if(response.error)
      {
        console.log("Error "+ response.error);
      }
    }
);
  });
});
```

I get an access token require error. However, how do I get an access token, without making the user to login? And how do I pass it to fb?

Thanks.

PS - yes i am replicating the social widget function, but with custom theming.

Comment: Get a page access token. (But those will allow anyone who can find it in the JS code act on behalf of the page – so this should rather be implemented server-side than client-side. Which would have the added benefit that you could to some caching, instead of doing a costly API call on every page load.)